# Attaching Entity Capabilities to Packet in Smack

Tags: xmpp, smack

I can't for the life of me see how to attach an Entity Capabilities extension to a Smack Packet.  In my case, I have the data ready to go, I just need to place it in the Packet class.

Am I missing something from the API?  Can I add the `<c/>` element to a smack Packet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an patch that adds Entity Capabilities support. The integration in Smack is tracked as [SMACK-361](http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SMACK-361) and the patch can be found in [the forum post.](http://community.igniterealtime.org/message/219006#219006)

The patch is included in [my smack fork](https://github.com/flowdalic/smack) (which get's used by [aSmack](https://github.com/flowdalic/asmack)). The `<c/>` element gets added in [ServiceDiscoveryManager.java:258](https://github.com/Flowdalic/smack/blob/master/source/org/jivesoftware/smackx/ServiceDiscoveryManager.java#L258), with help of the CapsExtension. I am still working on the Entity Caps support in Smack in the `caps` branch and hope to get it committed some time in the future. You can view the current patch with git by using `git diff upstream caps`, after you have cloned the repository. If you have any suggestions, feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 1):

Smack appears not to support this feature out of the box. You'll have to implement it yourself. Define a class that implements [PacketExtension](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/PacketExtension.html), create a new instance of this at the time of sending your presence and attach it using [addExtension](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/Packet.html#addExtension%28org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.PacketExtension%29).

Comment: actually it does, and Flow's answer above has helped me get rid of it.

Comment: Well he is sort of right. Smack has at the moment no Entity Caps support. But the patch is nearly finished and I expect it to go upstream within the next 2 months or so.